# Using a Select Value as a Json Var in Sort

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use the value from a select dropdown list as a variable for a Json filtering function. When I hardcode the value of a.(name), it works, but when I try to use the keyname var from the dropdown list it returns undefined.

```
function sortJson(a, b)
{
    //get sorting dropdown value for key
    var keyname = $('#sortByKey').val();// I want to dynamically set the keyname from dropdown. It traces correctly, so I am getting the value I want.

    if (a.keyname == b.keyname)//works when i hardcode a.name, or a.id etc...
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return a.keyname > b.keyname ? 1 : -1;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you juste have to write:

> a[keyname]

instead of

> a.keyname

Answer (score 1):

To reference the properties of the variable with the name specified by keyName, use the brackets syntax as another answer suggested:

```
a[keyname]
```

This is equivalent to a.key if keyname is key, but will allow you to use a dynamic string.

a.keyname tries to lookup the keyname property on a, which does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: No problem.  A bit of stack overflow advice, generally if you want to thank someone here, upvote their answer/question.  Thanks in the comments/question are generally frowned upon since they add noise: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question